# Meaning of "lu" in variable definition

Tags: c++

what does `lu` mean in this context:

```
size_t size = 10lu;
```

I have found nothing about it.
Thank you!

Comment: It's an unsigned long literal.

Comment: It means that the literal is forced to be of type `unsigned long`.

Comment: Read about [integer literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal), especially look at "The type of the literal" table on that page.

Comment: I didn't know you can't switch the letters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simplified: This means `unsigned long`.

Please also refer to [this.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/)